# Enabling Azure PaSs web app to communicate with Back office

Tags: azure, web-services, security, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

We are migrating our website on Azure platform in PaSS model. our website needs to communicate to our back office system using web services. 
Currently the Back Office system is in a providers data center. and we have a firewall which enables web service communication for specific IP's

Now website going to be hosted on Azure with PaSS model, can some one please advice which IP address we need to add in whitelist of our Back office firewall. 
Please note we want to set up our web app to be out-scaled to multiple instances. 
will each instance will be able to communicate with out Back office ?

Regards

Umesh Deshmukh

Answer (score 1):

> can some one please advice which IP address we need to add in
>   whitelist of our Back office firewall. Please note we want to set up
>   our web app to be out-scaled to multiple instances. will each instance
>   will be able to communicate with out Back office ?

For a long-term, Hybrid Connection is much better. If you still want to know whitelist the outbound IP of web app service, you could find these possible outbound IP addresses in **additional outbound IP addresses** setting of the web app properties. You can't know beforehand which IP address a given app instance will use to make the outbound connection, so your back-end service must open its firewall to all the outbound IP addresses of your app. You could get more details about [Inbound and outbound IP addresses in Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-inbound-outbound-ips).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use Azure Service Bus Relay to connect your web app to your on-premises database that's behind the firewall. Azure service bus relay uses internet port 80 so there should be no firewall issues. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Within an App Service is a feature called a Hybrid Connection, which can be found under the Networking section of the App Service you want to connect to your back office.

[image: Hybrid Connection in App Service]

You will create a new Hybrid Connection via the Portal. 
[image: Create Hybrid Connection]

Complete the form with the information that pertains to the back office system you want to connect to. You should always use a Fully Qualified Domain Name for all your back office systems. If you are connecting to multiple back office systems, you will need one Hybrid Connection for each one.

[image: Create new Hybrid Connection]

A Hybrid Connection relies on a Service Bus Relay to communicate with your on-premises resources.

You will install the Hybrid Connection Manager in your on-premises systems and connect it to the Service Bus Relay you created in the portal.

[image: Hybrid Connection Manager]

Once the Hybrid Connection you create in the Portal has been connected to a Hybrid Connection Manager (called a Listener), the connection will show as Connected in the Portal.

[image: Connected Hybrid Connections]

Once connected, an application running in an App Service will be able to communicate with your on-premises resources as if they were sitting right next to each other. There is going to be some inherent latency involved with using a Hybrid Connection and this should be planned for. The latency we have seen using Hybrid Connections have been minimal and are usually barely noticeable. I have even heard that people are streaming media from on-premises systems using Hybrid Connections.

More information about Hybrid Connections can be [found here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-hybrid-connections).